# How to determine video stream URL for videos inside an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

Is it possible to detect the URL of a streaming video that is shown within a 3rd-party iPhone app? Take the ESPN app, for example. How can we determine the video URL for one of its highlight videos? On the web they use Flash, but since Flash isn't possible on iOS, doesn't this mean the stream is coming from an accessible URL?

Answer (score 0):

When using Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/) you just have to be in the same wireless network and set the IP of the machine which is running Charles as Proxy on your mobile device.

On an iDevice go to the system settings, choose WLAN and tap on the "i" icon to get to the network configuration. Scroll down to HTTP_PROXY and set it to "manual". Add the IP as server entry and 8888 as port (unless you changed that in Charles). If everything works out Charles asks you for permission to let the iDevice connect to it.

If you also want to sniff SSL connections you have to install a certificate on your iDevice (http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/). If an app checks for the certificate it may stop working though.